# SSRS Report Parameter IsHidden value

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm using  ReportService2005 to return a list of parameters from SSRS. Some of these parameters are pre populated and hidden.

Is there a way to find out whether a parameter is hidden or not, I've looked over the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportparameter.aspx) for the ReportParameter class and can't find any reference to hidden.

I use the following code to get the parameters

```
bool forRendering = true;
string historyID = null;
ParameterValue[] values = null;
DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
ReportParameter[] parameters = null;

ReportingService2005SoapClient svc = new ReportingService2005SoapClient();

svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
svc.GetReportParameters(reportName, historyID, forRendering, values, credentials, out parameters);


SSRSParameter[] params = (from p in parameters
                      select new SSRSParameter()
                      {
                                     Name = p.Name,
                                     Type = p.Type,
                                     MultiSelect = p.MultiValue,
                                     Dependencies = p.Dependencies,
                                     CurrentValue = p.DefaultValues,
                                 }).ToArray();
return params;
```

Comment: Seems to work, however it hides both parameters that have a value by default and are not hidden and hidden parameters.